# MySQL Nested upto 5 filters

Tags: mysql, select, nested

I like to make a nested select upto 5 filters and I still at 3 filters. Here's the code.

```
    SELECT * FROM anvariety_trait
INNER JOIN
(SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait
    INNER JOIN (SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait
                    WHERE
                        trait_id = 1 and trait_value = 1) T2 USING (variety_id)
                    where
                        trait_id = 2 AND trait_value = 1) T3 USING (variety_id)
                        INNER JOIN tblVariety USING (variety_id)
                            WHERE
                            trait_id = 3 and trait_value = 1;
```

Comment: I bet, nobody understand your question. Add more details please.

Comment: Well, it's like the filter function of excel where you can select a certain value then it only shows rows with the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add filter by putting sub queries "INNER JOIN(SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait WHERE trait_id = 1 and trait_value = 1) T1 USING (variety_id)". I there is much easier and non complicated to do this but it works for me, for now.

```
SELECT * FROM anvariety_trait
INNER JOIN
(SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait
INNER JOIN (SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait
INNER JOIN(SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait
INNER JOIN(SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait
WHERE
trait_id = 1 and trait_value = 1) T1 USING (variety_id)
WHERE
trait_id = 2 and trait_value = 1) T2 USING (variety_id)
WHERE
trait_id = 3 and trait_value = 1) T3 USING (variety_id)
WHERE
trait_id = 4 AND trait_value = 1) T4 USING (variety_id)
INNER JOIN tblVariety USING (variety_id)
WHERE
trait_id = 6 and trait_value = 1;
```